# Trouble executing a Python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract information from a large output file from the program DL_POLY 4 and make it into a simpler file, formatted for some visualisation software.

Supposedly someone has already written a script to convert the large HISTORY output file (essentially just contains lots of text) into an .xyz (extension is arbitrary) which is the correct format to be processed by VMD. (full documentation from the script creator is available here: http://www.ccp5.ac.uk/DL_POLY_CLASSIC/FAQ/FAQ9.shtml)

Here is the script (also available [online](http://www.ccp5.ac.uk/DL_POLY_CLASSIC/FAQ/his2xyz.py)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,string

atomList=['Si','Al','O_','O','H','C','Cl','Na','Zr','Y_','Mg','K','Ag','Ar']
inputFile=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
outFile=open(sys.argv[2],'w')

title=inputFile.readline()
line=inputFile.readline()

while(line!=""): 
if string.split(line)[0]=='timestep':
    timestep='step= '+string.split(line)[1]+'\n'
    totalAtom=string.split(line)[2]+'\n'    
    outFile.write(totalAtom)
    outFile.write(timestep)

if string.split(line)[0][:2] in atomList:
        atomName=string.split(line)[0][:2]+'\t'
    outFile.write(atomName)
    xyzline=inputFile.readline()
    outFile.write(xyzline)

line=inputFile.readline()

inputFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

I have tried saving the script as a file I named his2xyz.py (In the directory containing the HISTORY file) and running through Python, but this does nothing and does not produce an output.

Does this script look like it should work?

I would like to try writing my own script, but in honesty, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Did you "add/modify the atom symbol in the atomList in this script" as instructed on the linked web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script takes two arguments. The first one is the input file and the second one the output file, so you have to run it like:

```
./his2xyz.py HISTORY the_output_file.xyz
```

Edit: You mentioned you would write your own script, but you don't know how to do it. Here is some life advice: If you don't know how to do something, ask a search engine - but you know that. If you really really really want to write a script, you need to learn Python first. There are many good books for this purpose on the market, but the official documentation is very well written, too. Start with the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) and have fun! :-)

Comment: Actually he has just discovered StackOverflow, chances he's already far away are high. Upvoted for him.

Comment: only 21 hours late!
Just seen you're edit - thanks for the advice! (seriously).